# Using Seq and seqcli for logging Java Springboot in real time

Tags: linux, spring-boot, stdin, seq, gelf

I'm trying to use Seq, which is a tool for logging management, mostly supported in .NET.
There are also tools like seqcli for sending logs to a seq server as shown here:

https://docs.datalust.co/docs/

The thing is, I'm using a springboot App, and according to the docs, I'm using GELF and Seq deployed as docker containers in a remote server. Everything is on Linux.

I managed to send some logs from a file using this command:

```
./seqcli ingest ../spring-boot-*.log
```

and I can see them on the remote server, but **I'm not able to send logs in realtime**. the docs says that I can send logs in real time from STDIN but no more details about it, I have no idea how can I achieve this.

https://docs.datalust.co/docs/command-line-client#extraction-patterns

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I was digging a little more throughout the docs and I found this:

```
tail -c 0 -F /var/log/syslog |  seqcli ingest
```

which I converted to this:

```
tail -c 0 -F ../spring-boot-app.log |  ./seqcli ingest
```

If someone runs into the same problem, look some more here:

https://blog.datalust.co/parsing-plain-text-logs-with-seqcli/

Comment: further more, you can add `nohup  tail -c 0 -F ../spring-boot-app.log |  ./seqcli ingest > /dev/null 2>& 1 &` to run it on background